# Searching a text with space in mySql match against Query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, php, subquery

I want to search a text in mysql DB with [space] (Ascii 32) as a part of it. But I am not getting the correct result.

My MySql Query is:

```
SELECT count(id) as total
    , MIN(product_price) as min_price
    , MAX(product_price) as max_price 
FROM `products_details` 
WHERE subcat_id = 1026 
    AND MATCH(alternate_name, product_desc, keywords)
    AGAINST ('+moto +g +plus +(>mobile <mobiles)'; IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I have problem with:

> `AGAINST ('+moto +g +plus +(>mobile <mobiles)'`

I want to search for string `moto g plus` mobile,using the above query. I want to add space before and after the `g`. Example, `moto "SPACE"g"SPACE"`.

I tried with the 2 following solns, its not working.

[[:space:]]

> `AGAINST ('+moto +[[:space:]]g[[:space:]] +plus +(>mobile <mobiles)'`

and

> `AGAINST ('+moto +\\ g\\  +plus +(>mobile <mobiles)'`  ==> I have a space character (Ascii 32) after the \ in this query

Both of them are not working.

Can you please let me know what should be there?

Edit: The value of ft_min_word_len is set 1.

Comment: `g` is just too short for fulltext indexes to take it into account. But you can leave it from the match and add another condition `(alternate_name LIKE 'moto g plus' OR product_desc LIKE ...)`. That way you use the fulltext index to get "interesting" rows and then the LIKE filters only these (hopefully few) for exact match.

Comment: Thank you, but the query has to be like what I wanted. The reason is, Your suggestion might work for some situations, and in other conditions, it will not work.

Answer (score 6):

`FULLTEXT` needs space to be space, not a "letter".  That is, you *cannot* have spaces in a "word".

I would write application code to ignore 'short' words (such as 'g') and end up with

```
WHERE MATCH(alternate_name, product_desc, keywords)
        AGAINST ('+moto +plus'; IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND ( alternate_name LIKE '%moto g plus%'
     OR product_desc   LIKE '%moto g plus%'
     OR keywords       LIKE '%moto g plus%' )
```

That would be efficient because the `MATCH` happens first, thereby limiting the number of rows significantly.  Then the costly `OR` and `LIKE` does not have to touch many rows.

(I left off the 'mobiles' for this discussion.)